# Hibernate Collection is Null on update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Consider the following:

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {


    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ChildEntity childEntity;
}

@Entity
public class ChildEntity {


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(FALSE)
    private List<AnotherEntity> otherEntities;
}
```

Now, when i first call

```
final ChildEntity anewChild = new ChildEntity();
    anewChild.addOtherEntity(anotherEntity); //Several Entities can be added here
    mainEntity.setChildEntity(anewChild);
EntityManager.persist(mainEntity);
```

Everything works fine, and then i do some updates, long after the transaction is finished.

```
final ChildEntity anotherNewChild = new ChildEntity();
anotherNewChild.addOtherEntity(anotherEntity); //Several Entities can be added here
mainEntity.setChildEntity(anotherNewChild);

//A log of LOG.info(mainEntity); shows all fields appropriately set
//At some point during merge operation, the new ChildEntity will need to be persisted.
 //According to my logs, an invocation of EntityManager.persist(anotherNewChild) occurs, during as the merge is propagated to the new entity.
//At this point is where the ChildEntity.otherEntities is detected to be null
return EntityManager.merge(mainEntity);
```

The problem is that, with persist, the

> `List<AnotherEntity>`

is not null and not empty, while on merge, the

> `List<AnotherEntity>`

is null

I am doing this over ejb remote invocation.

> Hibernate 4.3.6 
>   wildfly 8.1.0
>   jpa 2.1

Is there something i am missing here?

Reproduced issue with the following code:

https://github.com/marembo2008/hibernate-jpa-bug

Opened an issue on Hibernate Issue tracker.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9751

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that merge returns a new entity, so you should do something like this:

```
mainEntity = EntityManager.merge(mainEntity);
```

Comment: I do exactly that. Since i do remote ejb invocation, i wouldn't return anything other than that. Please see my edit to the question